# Raphael.js: [Onclick] Change color of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have build a map of the US in Raphael.js. Now I want that every time when a state is clicked it changes colour in kind of a loop.
 Like this:

> White State --> Click --> Blue State --> Click --> Red --> Click --> White --> Click --> Blue and so on.

The following code works just once. Like when the fill colour of a state is set to blue, the colour onclick changes to red, but on the next click it just stays red and does not change to white. Does someone have a solution?

```
for(var i = 0; i< states.length; i++) {
 states[i].click(function() {
  if (this.attr('fill')=='white')
    {this.node.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');}
  else if (this.attr('fill')=='blue')
     {this.node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');}
  else {this.node.setAttribute('fill', 'white');}
});
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Think you may need to include a bit more code to be sure, ideally on a jsfiddle. Also note, you don't need to use 'this.node.setAttribute', just use 'this.attr(' like you did when checking.

Comment: Thank you! Just replaced the '.node' and now it works. How do i give you the green hook? Sorry new here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, This works (Thanks to Ian):

```
for(var i = 0; i< states.length; i++) {
states[i].click(function() {
if (this.attr('fill')=='white')
  {this.attr('fill', 'blue');}
else if (this.attr('fill')=='blue')
  {this.attr('fill', 'red');}
else {this.attr('fill', 'white');}
});
}
```